# vue material md-input focus behaviour

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-material

This is an odd one so I hope this makes sense.

I have a login form that i'm trying to adapt vue material components, it currently looks like this

```
<template>
<md-layout>
  <md-layout md-flex="100" md-align="center">
    <form class="login-form" role="form" @submit.prevent="submit">
        <md-input-container>
            <div v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': errors.email }">
                <label>enter email address</label>
                <md-input v-model="email" required></md-input>
                <span class="help-block" v-if="errors.email">{{ errors.email[0] }}</span>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
            <div v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': errors.password }">
                <label>enter password</label>
                <md-input type="password" v-model="password" required></md-input>
                <span class="help-block" v-if="errors.password">{{ errors.password[0] }}</span>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Login</md-button>
    </form>
  </md-layout>
</md-layout>
</template>
```

The submit code in brief

```
methods: {
        submit() {
            console.log('login...');
        }
}
```

The weird behavior is that when I click in the input label, unless i click the absolute left most of the field, it does NOT take focus and I cannot type in it.  So if you imagine the placeholder text as above "enter email address", unless I click right on the "e" in the "enter....", it does not work !  (or if I tab into it, it will take focus as expected)

Any ideas based on that code ?

The login-form styles is not doing anything crazy:

```
.login-form {
   background: #FFFFFF;
   min-width: 40vh;
   padding: 65px;
   text-align: center;
   box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

Also, if anyone can suggest how to auto focus the first email field that would be great - the vue material docs don't say much (as far as I've found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't provide a '(don't) working' example I should `especulate` a litte. I use Vue-material and I don't have any input problems, but we use the `md-input-container` element to wrap our inputs without a `div` inside, like:

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Initial value</label>
    <md-input v-model="initialValue"></md-input>
</md-input-container>
```

Another think to take a look is the `min-width: 40vh;`. If you change it to a fixed width (i.e 100px), still occurs the same effect? Or maybe the span is overlapping over your input... Have you tried to debug with `Inspector`?

In order to focus in the email input you can archieve it by adding `ref` option, like:

```
<md-input v-model="email" required ref='emailInput' ></md-input>
```

and in the `mounted()` function you can set:

```
this.$refs.emailInput.focus()
```

Hope it helps to you!

Comment: that was silly of me - thanks you were right - the outer div was in fact covering the label and causing that issue, thanks !